# Scope of if var closure on Swift

Tags: swift

I'm implementing an adjacency list using Swift.

Now I want to addEdge, and if that value already exists in the dictionary I want to append a new edge.

However, the scope of if var seems to only be within the following closure, meaning

```
if var child = children[from] {
    // child exists
    child.append(to)
}
```

does not produce the intended result, but the following does

```
if var child = children[from] {
    children[from]!.append(to)
}
```

but this looks ugly and, frankly wrong.

What is the best way of appending to the dictionary in this case?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `children[from]` is a **value** type which is why your append is not reflecting on the original. Can you show the type of children?

Comment: var children = [ Int : [Int] ]()

Comment: Since the question isn't related to `if var ...` scoping, you should change the title. Something like _value isn't updated in the dictionary_ or any similar you think.

Comment: It applies to any value type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your dictionary value is a **value type** `[Int]`, a *copy* of the dictionary value is made and given to `child`. This means that any changes you make to child will not reflect in the dictionary. So, you need to replace the value with the one to which you have made the changes.

```
if var child = children[from] {
    child.append(to)
    children[from] = child
}
```

Or simply,

```
children[from]?.append(to)
```